# scaledToHeight() does not scale to height - PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to render my image, but scaled to the height of the current window and keeping with aspect ratio.

The following does just that, but does not actually scale the image:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Img(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Img, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: orange')

        window = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)
        height = window.height()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        pixmap = QPixmap("test.png")
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(height)
        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setScaledContents(True)

        layout.addWidget(label)

        print(height)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        img = Img()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(img)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        content = QWidget()
        content.setLayout(layout)

        w,h = (1024,670)
        self.resize(w,h)
        self.setCentralWidget(content)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Although it prints out height is `1050`, what I see is a huge image and the window expands down past my monitor. Can someone explain the issue and what needs to happen for `scaledToHeight()`?

Here is an example of what I see:
[image]

And here is the actual image:
[image]

The image gets cut off because it gets extended past the monitor screen, and is also stretched oddly.

Comment: remove `label.setScaledContents(True)`

Comment: @eyllanesc I removed that line but the image is still extending past the monitor screen.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited my post to include some screenshots

Comment: Try to change `window = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(0)` to `window = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()`

Comment: @S.Nick That didn't seem to work either. Also how come the initial window size does not get respected? I've originally set the window to be `w,h = (1024,670)`, but the result extends the window way past `670`, and then offscreen in my monitor?